# start xen vm using cli, without creating configuration files

Tags: xen

Is it possible to start virtal machine without creating configuration files? Only by specifying all configuration parameters through command line, like QEMU. Can you give some references or examples?

Answer (score 0):

You sure can! If you are using the xm toolstack:

http://linux.die.net/man/1/xm

Has some info on how to do it specifically:

"This creates a domain with the file /etc/xen/Fedora4, and returns as soon as it is run.
without config file"

```
xm create /dev/null ramdisk=initrd.img \
   kernel=/boot/vmlinuz-2.6.12.6-xenU \
   name=ramdisk vif='' vcpus=1 \
   memory=64 root=/dev/ram0
```

Beware though, you may not like the outcome of doing it like this. You cannot edit the settings that don't have a command line equivalent(That I know of, reference my question for more info on this [xm re-create configuration file from existing vm](https://serverfault.com/questions/527823/xm-re-create-configuration-file-from-existing-vm))