# xm re-create configuration file from existing vm

Tags: virtualization, debian-wheezy, xen

I have Xen set up and working quite nicely.

When I reboot and use:

```
xm list
```

I get this output:

```
Name                                        ID   Mem VCPUs      State   Time(s)
Domain-0                                     0  4096     4     r-----    153.6
busiserver                                      2048     2                26.0
testserver0                                     2048     2              1596.1
ubuntuserver                                    1024     2                47.8
```

This is because I created 3 vms through the xm command line by using something like

```
xm create create /dev/null ramdisk=initrd.img \
   kernel=/boot/vmlinuz-2.6.12.6-xenU \
   name=ramdisk vif='' vcpus=1 \
   memory=64 root=/dev/ram0
```

I also created one vm through a regular configuration file. This vm does not appear in the output of xm list, and cannot be interacted with in any way unless I use

```
xm create missingvm.cfg
```

At which point, it functions as expected, and all data from previous sessions is restored. I would like to know

1. Where are "xm create" configuration files located when you use the pure command line      option(so that I may edit/remove them)?
2. If they are not stored anywhere since I used the command line options, is there a way to export/infer what the configuration file would look like for an existing vm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the `.sxp` configurations used by xen in `/var/lib/xend/domains/`. You can create a machine from a `.sxp` file by using `xm create -F=FILE` (see `man xm`).

However, if you want to edit them I'd reccomend you to use libvirt's API or using `virsh`: `virsh edit VMNAME`.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you. Is there a way to add a vm created from a configuration file to this list? Or should I ask that in a separate question?

Comment: Those are files managed directly by xen, so you have to use `xm new <cfg file>` to add a new domain to the Xen managed domains.